# How to run two 'foreach' codes together to get output as one?

Tags: php

I have two `foreach` loops. One gives `image href="URL"s` and the other gives `image src="URL"s`.

How do I combine these two loops together and display images?

My code which gives image HREFs:

```
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $a){
    foreach($a->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img){
        echo $a->getAttribute('href');
    }
}
```

My code which gives image SRCs:

```
foreach($html->find('img') as $e)
    echo $e->src . '<br>';
```

Comment: Couple of questions:  1) Are `$html` and `$doc` coming from the same original HTML source, or two separate sources? 2) As Beenish pointed out, the `href` doesn't point to the image, it points to wherever the image is linking to, so do you need the image location or the link or both in that case?

Comment: I just noticed that `find()` is a method for a 3rd party library.  Are you using the same library for `$doc` and `$html`?  Are they different sources? Is there a reason to use PHP's DOM library for `$doc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following.

```
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $a){
    echo $a->getAttribute('href');
    foreach($a->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img){
        echo $img->src . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Your code is echoing `a->href` for every image. If that's what you want to do, then try the following.

```
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $a){
    foreach($a->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img){
        echo $a->getAttribute('href');
        echo $img->src . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: I think they might be two different objects using two totally different classes, so your first part might not work. But good call regarding the href vs src.

Answer (score 1):

I'll think on this as far as how to get it all done in one loop, but until then, here is how to get them all into one array:

```
$image_links = array();

foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $a){
    foreach($a->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img){
        $image_links[] = $a->getAttribute('href');
    }
}

foreach($html->find('img') as $e)
    $image_links[] = $e->src;
 }
```